# Facebook Like and Share information not showing properly

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like

I made my website [My SMS Buddy](http://www.eravikant.com) and i have included one facebook like button to sharing my website on facebook. But, whenever i clicked on the like button, it is only showing my website url,but it is not showing thumbnail,title,description, although i have written the code for all the information inside the main page. This is the sample code of the main page

```
<head>
<meta property="og:title" content="My SMS Buddy" />
<meta property="og:type" content="activity" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.eravikant.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.eravikant.com/images/image.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My SMS Buddy" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="100002723853376" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Share and Send Free Sms Anywhere In India Which Support Upto 160 Characters Long Sms Without Any Advertisements Attached with the Sms To Any Mobile In India With Easy Group Messaging" />
</head>

<body>
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.eravikant.com&amp;send=false&amp;layout=box_count&amp;width=60&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=segoe+ui&amp;height=90" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:60px; height:90px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</body>
```

Need suggestion, what am doing wrong here... 
Suggestion will be appreciated ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some really odd things in your page's HTML. You have duplicates of your opening and closing HEAD, BODY and wrapping HTML tags. This is invalid HTML and doesn't parse at all. This also won't show your page properly in web browsers since it won't know which part of the HTML to render. This is what is confusing Facebook.

Remove the first HTML opening and closing (plus its contents) and Facebook should get your OG Metadata fine. It's in the second HTML HEAD metadata and that looks fine.

Comment: thank you so much for your valuable reply.. but, i am still facing the same problem..

Comment: Executing the fix I suggested has actually fixed this for you. Facebook takes some time to clear its cache. As a test, check out your URL from their Developer testing page: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.eravikant.com%2F All of your data is coming through fine. Once the cache clears you're all set.

Comment: Liam is right.. you have to remove your duplicate html and head tags from the main page, which will help for parsing the value. And, also you have to debug you website url from [Facebook Developer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to check for any mistake or correctness of the information.
You can also refer any blog, where tutorial for these type of social plugins are available..